# XTemplate does not work

Tags: extjs

I am using ExtJs with XTemplate and I need to use the tag `<if>` to select a specific model in my store, however when I run this code: `'<tpl if="id == {id}">',` appears an error saying

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Can anyone provide me an insight ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode it, have a look at the basic math support example: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate

Comment: Yes, I encoded this and the code was like this : `'<tpl if="id &#61;&#61; {id}">'`, but the same error still happend.